# Is it possible to wait the main thread while all the threads of executor service are processing tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am having a scenario of around inserting millions of data into the back end and currently using executor framework to load this. I will explain my problem in simpler terms.

In the below case, I am having 10 runnable and  three threads to execute the same. Consider my runnable is doing an insert operation and it is taking time to complete the  task. When I checked ,It is understood that ,if all the threads are busy, the other tasks will go to the queue and once the threads completed the tasks ,it will fetch the tasks from the pool and complete it.

So in this case, object of SampleRunnable 4 to 10 will be created and this will be in the pool.

Problem: Since I need to load millions of tasks,I cannot load all the records in queue which can lead to memory issues. So my question is instead of taking all tasks in the queue  ,is it possible to make the main thread waiting  until any one of the executor worker threads becomes available.

Following approaches  I tried as a work around instead of queuing this much tasks:

Approach 1: Used Array Blocking Queue for executor and gave the size as 5 (for e.g.)
So in this case, when the 9th task comes ,this will throw RejectedExecutionException and in the catch clause,put a sleep for 1 minute and recursively trying the same.This will get picked up on any of the retry when the thread is available.

Approach 2:  Used shut down and await termination. i.e. if the task count is 5, i am putting shut down and await termination. In the await Termination 'if' block (executor.awaitTermination(60000,TimeUnit.SECONDS)),I am instantiating the thread pool again.

```
public class SampleMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){ 
   executorService.execute(new SampleRunnable(i));
}

executor.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is, you want to throttle the main thread, so that it does not get ahead of the workers. If that's the case, then consider explicitly constructing a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance instead of calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`.

That class has several different constructors, and most of them allow you to supply your own blocking queue.  If you create an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a limited size, then every time the queue becomes full, the main thread will be automatically blocked until a worker makes room by taking another task.

```
final int work_queue_size = 30;
BlockingQueue work_queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(work_queue_size);
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(..., work_queue);

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){ 
    executorService.execute(new SampleRunnable(i));
}
...
```

Comment: I tried this solution on Approach 1. In this case,instead of main thread getting blocked,this will throw RejectedExecutionException i.e. if all the threads are busy and queue is full.

Comment: `final static BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(5);
 static ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3,
         0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
         queue);
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
   executorService.execute(new SampleRunnable(i));
  }
  executorService.shutdown();
 }` .This is the code snippet I tried and this will throw the exception for the 9 th record.

Comment: Oops! Yeah. I think you need to also provide a `RejectedExecutionHandler`. If you supply the `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` for the handler, then you should not get the exception because a new task simply will be performed on the main thread any time the main thread tries to submit and the queue is full.  (As you probably can tell, I haven't done this myself. I only looked in the documentation to see how I would solve the problem if it was my problem.)

Comment: `new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,queue,new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());` -- Added the above code while instantiating the executor and this is working for me. i.e. In this case the thread pool size is 5 and active threads are 3. So when the 8th task came, it not get  executed  and no exception also populated. Also main thread seems  to be in waiting state during that time.   If that is the case, I need  to determine the  correct pool size, and I can use this solution to check the performance.